# LINQ nested select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 `class` as follow:

```
public class Outlet
{
    [Key]
    public int outletID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string outletCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string outletName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Opening Date")]
    public DateTime outletOpeningDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int managerID { get; set; }

    public User manager { get; set; }

    public int supervisorID { get; set; }

    public User supervisor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string outletAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Unit No")]
    public string outletUnitNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string outletPostalCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone No")]
    public string outletPhoneNo { get; set; }

    public bool deleted { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int userID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Email Address.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Roles")]
    public int rolesID { get; set; }

    public Role roles { get; set; }

    public bool deleted { get; set; }
}
```

inside my outlet class i have this 2 user `class` instance

```
public User manager { get; set; }
public User supervisor { get; set; }
```

i need to get all `outlet` list, and get the manager detail (from user table) based on `managerID (FK: userid in table user)`
and get supervisor detail (also from user table) based on `supervisorID (FK: userid in table user)`

i tried this `linq`:

```
IEnumerable<Outlet> outlet = (
                    from o in db.Outlets
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    select new Outlet
                    {

                        outletID = o.outletID,
                        outletCode = o.outletCode,
                        outletName = o.outletName,
                        outletOpeningDate = o.outletOpeningDate,
                        managerID = o.managerID,

                        supervisorID = o.supervisorID,
                        outletAddress = o.outletAddress,
                        outletUnitNo = o.outletUnitNo,
                        outletPostalCode = o.outletPostalCode,
                        outletPhoneNo = o.outletPhoneNo,

                        manager = db.Users.Where(u => u.deleted == false).Where(u => u.userID == o.managerID).FirstOrDefault(),

                        supervisor = db.Users.Where(u => u.deleted == false).Where(u => u.userID == o.supervisorID).FirstOrDefault()
                    });

return View(outlet.ToList());
```

but i get this error:
`Invalid column name 'manager_userID'.
Invalid column name 'supervisor_userID'.`

how to do nested select using linq with class inside class?

sorry for my poor english, hope you could understand what i mean..

Comment: You don't have `manager_userID` in your code you have `managerID` is that a typo ?

Comment: Hi, the field name in select query is seem to be automatically generated, so it become manager_userID, i tried to rename it, but it then create another problem (please see below comment)

Answer (score 2):

There are more problems that need to be addressed with your code.
What you need to make sure is that you can do it in SQL before writing a LINQ query.

Basically the following code should do the trick (unfortunately I can't test it right now..).

**Note**: Just because there exist 4 queries doesn't mean that there will be 4 executed queries between your app and the DB.
**Note2**: Just because there is just one query that gets executed between your app and the DB doesn't mean that the DB doesn't have to do 3 individual passes through the indexes.

```
var query1 = from user in db.Users
             join outlet in db.Outlets
             on user equals outlet.manager
             select new { outlet, user };
var query2 = from user in db.Users
             join outlet in db.Outlets
             on user equals outlet.supervisor
             select new { outlet, user };
var query3 = from outlet in db.Outlets
             where (outlet.manager == null) && (outlet.supervisor == null)
             select new { outlet = outlet, user = null as User };
var unionQuery = query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3);

List<Outlet> all = unionQuery
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(obj => obj.outlet)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();

return View(all);
```

The simple fact that we're explicitly requesting the `manager` and `supervisor` relationship properties in those queries is instructing the ORM that we need them to be eagerly loaded ahead of time.

Good luck :)